# MahApps Metro- React on Tab Close in VS Styled Tabcontrol

Tags: mahapps.metro

I am using a VS styled Tabcontrol (from the MahApps.Metro Project) in a Project with the Caliburn.Micro framework and I am looking for a way to let my ViewModel which inherits from Conductor.Collection.OneActive know when a Tab is being closed. Unfortunately the close button is already included in the style, and that is confusing me a bit. I looked up in the MahApps Source files for this VS Tabcontrol style, and found that each close button is bound to a CloseCommmand (Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"). How can I react to a click of that button?

Answer (score 0):

Attach `DeactivateItem` event to the close button.

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="DeactivateItem($dataContext, 'true')" />
```

The `DeactivateItem` is a framework method of caliburn micro, defined in Conductor class.
This method will close the associated view and removes the view from Conductor Collection.

FYI:

Framework method.

```
public override void DeactivateItem(T item, bool close) {
            if(item == null || !item.Equals(ActiveItem))
                return;

            CloseStrategy.Execute(new[] { ActiveItem }, (canClose, items) => {
                if(canClose)
                    ChangeActiveItem(default(T), close);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the CloseTabCommand will trigger the Unloaded event, My workaround is attach a handler to it.

```
public partial class MyTab : MetroTabItem {

    public MyTab() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Unloaded += dosomthing;
    }

    public void dosomething(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```